# slider bug + Post thumbnail questions / Smartstart WP Theme

Tags: slider

I'm working with the Smartstart theme for Wordpress and i've a problem with the slider i put on my [home page](http://www.rcahandball.com)

- There is an high space between the "slogan" and the slider
- The texts and icons in the bottom are not stylized as they used to be...
  I don't really know what happened because everything was fine few days ago... can someone help me ?

Other point : does somenone know how to fix the post thumbnails height on the home page and on  the ["blog" page](http://www.rcahandball.com/actualites/)? The width is already fixed.

Finally, i would like to hide the post thumbnail on the post pages...

Can someone help me ? The author doesn't respond...